# dotnet test runsettings throwing MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, selenium, .net-core

Tried running the selenium c# dotnet test with the run settings file from the Terminal mac os. Facing MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch.

Framework used is NUnit 3.x

```
dotnet test --settings config.runsettings 
--TestRunParameters.Parameter\(name=\"d\",\ value=\"Firefox\"\)
```

> MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch.
> Switch: --TestRunParameters.Parameter(name=d, value=Firefox)
>
> For switch syntax, type "MSBuild -help"

Comment: I'd expect `TestRunParameters` to be *in* config.runsettings, not specified on the command line.

Comment: I want to run the TestRunParameters at the run time.Say I need to pass Chrome from the command line @JonSkeet

Comment: You have 7 backslashes.  Why one before a space?

Comment: @jdweng - That's how it was specified in the https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/master/docs/RunSettingsArguments.md

Comment: I think it is a typo.  The first to examples do not have the extra backslash.

Comment: I suspect you're just missing the space after `--` and before `TestRunParameters`.

Comment: I don't think the backslashes are typos at all. They're escaping characters in the shell. (For example, the space is escaped to make sure it stays as a single command-line argument.) The first two examples don't have anything that needs escaping, that's all.

Comment: I suspect you want: `dotnet test --settings config.runsettings 
-- TestRunParameters.Parameter\(name=\"d\",\ value=\"Firefox\"\)`. Note that that *is* how the examples are specified on the page.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes ! I'll be having a runsettings file, where I'll have all the browser level information. I need to pass on the browser that I want to run from the Testrun parameters via my terminal. If I try running the above command, my terminal throws

MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch.
Switch: --TestRunParameters.Parameter(name=d, value=Firefox)

For switch syntax, type "MSBuild -help"

Comment: @RajeshG: Just to check, when you say "the above command" if you were referring to my previous comment, did you keep the space between "--" and "TestRunParameters"? That space was very deliberately present.

Comment: If I remove the space...Format: TestRunParameters.Parameter(name=\"<name>\", value=\"<value>\"). I dint use space though in terminal